# Unable to use this jquery-ui.js function accordion for GUI in HotTowel SPA whicle combining viewmodel with jquery Ui

Tags: jquery-ui, hottowel

The following code works well in browser. Which gives some Sliding up and down UI.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

But when I tired using this code in Hottowel SPA is not working can anyone tell me how to make this function work in HotTowel SPA template. Here I am trying to combine jquery-ui.js and viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include these scripts

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/koui.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
```

Use jqueryUi functions in knockout bindings

Filters 
                Value

```
        </ul>
    </section>
    <div id="filter">
        <div class="mytbody">
            <section>
                <ul class="mytr" style="width: 100%;">
                    <li class=" mytd">IsActive</li>
                    <li class="mytd">
                        <select class="filters" data-bind="options: ['True', 'False'], value: searchName"></select></li>
                    <li class="mytd">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: $root.search">Go</button></li>
                </ul>
                <!--Enter for accordion slide down-->
                <ul class="mytr" style="width: 100%;">
                    <li class=" mytd">Jobs Created before</li>
                    <li class="mytd">
                        <input class="filters" readonly="true" data-bind="value: dateTextBfr, jqueryui: { widget: 'datepicker', options: { showPeriod: true } }" type="datetime" /></li>
                    <li class="mytd">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: searchDateBfr">Go</button></li>
                </ul>
                <!--Enter for accordion slide down-->
                <ul class=" mytr" style="width: 100%;">
                    <li class=" mytd">Jobs Created after</li>
                    <li class="mytd">
                        <input class="filters" readonly="true" data-bind="value: dateTextAfr, jqueryui: { widget: 'datepicker', options: { showPeriod: true } }" type="datetime" /></li>
                    <li class="mytd">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: searchDateAftr">Go</button></li>
                </ul>
                <!--Enter for accordion slide down-->
            </section>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```